# How do I disable options in angularjs with ng-options when using select as label

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-options

I've got these variables in a service:

```
months: [
        { label: 'January', value: 1, disabled: true },
        { label: 'February', value: 2, disabled: true },
        { label: 'March', value: 3, disabled: true },
        { label: 'April', value: 4, disabled: false },
        { label: 'May', value: 5, disabled: false },
        { label: 'June', value: 6, disabled: false },
        { label: 'July', value: 7, disabled: false },
        { label: 'August', value: 8, disabled: false },
        { label: 'September', value: 9, disabled: false },
        { label: 'October', value: 10, disabled: false },
        { label: 'November', value: 11, disabled: false },
        { label: 'December', value: 12, disabled: false }
    ],
currentMonth: 4
```

my select looks like this:

```
<select name="goalStartMonth" id="goalStartMonth" class="form-control gb-select" ng-model="startMonth" ng-change="frequencyUpdated()" ng-options="month.value as month.label for month in months"></select>
```

that works fine to build the `<select>`, but I want to disable the months before the current month (can't select a month in the past)

Angular docs for ng-options show:

"label disable when disable for value in array"

so I've tried:

```
<select name="goalStartMonth" id="goalStartMonth" class="form-control gb-select" ng-model="startMonth" ng-change="frequencyUpdated()" ng-options="month.value as month.label disable when month.value < currentMonth for month in months"></select>
```

That breaks the `<select>` - no options are rendered.

I also tried:

```
<select name="goalStartMonth" id="goalStartMonth" class="form-control gb-select" ng-model="startMonth" ng-change="frequencyUpdated()" ng-options="month.label disable when month.value < currentMonth for month in months"></select>
```

same result.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: seems like it wasn't available in that version. in 1.4.0 your code works

Comment: Well this is embarassing when I switched the angular api docs to 1.3.11 (it defaults to the latest version apparently), 'disable when' disappears magically from the doc - you are correct sir!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to use an `ng-repeat` and `ng-disabled` on an `<option>` within the `<select>`, like this:

```
<select name="goalStartMonth" id="goalStartMonth" class="form-control gb-select" ng-model="startMonth" ng-change="frequencyUpdated()">
    <option ng-repeat="month in months" ng-disabled="month.value < currentMonth" >{{month.label}}</option>
</select>
```

Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2650xweb/)

> EDIT

As was mentioned above, this feature was not available until the 1.4.0 beta. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/k1angv1h/1/) is a JSFiddle showing it works using the 1.4.0-beta.6 version of AngularJS

Comment: Yeah that's my fallback approach if I can't get ng-options to do it.  We're using ng-options everywhere else in the app and I was hoping to stay consistent with that.

Comment: Yes - this is the way to go if your angular version is < 1.4.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know why it's not working. I checked the ng-options documentation from Angular docs and noticed they had an example using that "label disable when disable for value in array" notation.

I tried changing from 1.4.0-beta.6 to 1.3.15 in their example on plnkr and it didn't work anymore.

It seems like it is a version issue.

If you check https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/638
you will see that this disable notation was recently added, as this issue was closed on February 18.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable using ngOptions in angular 1.4.1 or above

HTML template

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<form ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select id="t1" ng-model="curval" ng-options='reportingType.code as reportingType.itemVal disable when reportingType.disable for reportingType in reportingOptions'>
        <option value="">Select Report Type</option>
    </select>

</form></div>
```

Controller code

---

```
angular.module('myapp',[]).controller("ctrl", function($scope){
$scope.reportingOptions=[{'code':'text','itemVal':'TEXT','disable':false}, {'code':'csv','itemVal':'CSV','disable':true}, {'code':'pdf','itemVal':'PDF','disable':false}];})
```